# Error running react native project using async storage on web platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, webpack

I am trying to run a React Native test app on a web platform. 
I have installed `@react-native-community/async-storage` dependency.
It generates the following error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/lib/AsyncStorage.js 40:5
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (40:5)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   | }
>   |
>   type ReadOnlyArrayString = $ReadOnlyArray;
>   |
>   | type MultiGetCallbackFunction = (
>    @ ./node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/lib/index.js 5:0-42 7:15-27
>    @ ./src/app.js
>    @ ./index.web.js
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./index.web.js
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/lib/hooks.js 7:5
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:5)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   | import AsyncStorage from './AsyncStorage';
>   |
>    type AsyncStorageHook = {
>   |   getItem: (
>   |     callback?: ?(error: ?Error, result: string | null) => void,
>    @ ./node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/lib/index.js 8:0-40 8:0-40
>    @ ./src/app.js
>    @ ./index.web.js
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./index.web.js

Note: Code is running on Android, but it is not running on Web.

Comment: What do you mean "not running on web" for you `React Native` project? do you mean a `webView`?

Answer (score 2):

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '@react-native-community/async-storage': 'react-native-web'
    }
}
```

create a resolve alias in your webpack.config.json.

This might help you